# Mobile HTML text input autocomplete doesn't reset when focused and reset

Tags: javascript, html, input, mobile, autocomplete

Trying to build a simple HTML/JS chat functionality and when a user selects "submit" the message is sent and the focus is on the text input, cleared. However, the autocomplete remains from the last word (on mobile). I want the autocomplete feature but need it to CLEAR on submit and reset.

[image: autocomple after reset on mobile]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The autocomplete remians on reset</h1>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="message" name="message" ><br><br>
  <input type="reset" onclick="myFunction()">
</form>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("message").value ='';
        document.getElementById("message").focus();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After much searching, I think the answer is YOU CANNOT DO IT programmatically. It appears that on mobile, iPhone at least, ONLY the user keyboard commands like RETURN or Backspace can affect the autocomplete. I solved the issue by hiding the button on Mobile and forcing the user to use the keyboard. So basically NO reset button on mobile.